# Programming a SQL UDF

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, psql

just started to getting used to SQL, etc and so my question is how the syntax is when creating an SQL UDF to retrieve information from a database, like for example, the database has the data, but im just creating an udf to retrieve information based on the requirements in a normal SQL Query.

I've been trying to search for the correct syntax to use but the examples provided aren't quite clear.

For example lets say I'm trying to attempt this query:

```
Select personName
from class
where personNumber = 9872
```

Been trying to find resources but haven't been successful.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried searching here or google for how to create a UDF? what was up with the answers you were given? how was it not clear? which part of the process did you have trouble with?

Comment: I was testing some UDF's I made from what I read on the internet and everytime I tried passing it through a script, I kept getting errors such as my syntax not correct

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server you can try

```
CREATE TABLE class
    (personNumber int, personName varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO class
    (personNumber, personName)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C'),
    (4, 'D'),
    (5, 'E'),
    (6, 'F')
;

CREATE FUNCTION InlineTableFunction(@ID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT *
FROM class
WHERE PersonNumber = @ID;

CREATE FUNCTION MultistatementFunction(@ID INT)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE(personNumber int, personName varchar(6)) 
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
  SELECT *
  FROM class
  WHERE PersonNumber = @ID
  RETURN
END;

CREATE FUNCTION ScalarFunction(@ID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @personName VARCHAR(60)
  SELECT @personName = personName
  FROM class
  WHERE personNumber = @ID
  return @personName
END;
```

and usage

```
SELECT *
FROM InlineTableFunction(3);

SELECT *
FROM MultistatementFunction(4);

SELECT dbo.ScalarFunction(5) as PersonName;
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89d8a/2)

Here is the actual SQL SERVER Reference

[CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a scalar user defined function in MySql is similar:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetPersonName(PersonID INT)
 RETURNS NVARCHAR(30)
  RETURN (SELECT Name
          FROM Person
          WHERE ID = PersonID);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c91cc/1)

However, be careful when using scalar UDF's, as they discourage set-based queries.

e.g. Never do this

```
SELECT p.Id, GetPersonName(p.Id)
FROM Person p;
```

As it will evaluate the UDF for each row in the result set.